# Why is Stark/Avengers tower not visible in the skyline in Jessica Jones?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers, jessica-jones-2015

There are several very clear skyline shots over the course of Season 1 of *Jessica Jones*. However, not in a single one of them is Stark/Avengers tower visible.

[image: NY Skyline]

From my understanding of the timeline, Season 1 takes place well after the first *Avengers* movie. Additionally, [the announcement trailer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sSCJj3nOSfQ) for Jessica Jones displays Avengers tower in one scene (around the 32 second mark).

Why is such an obvious sign of the MCU blatantly absent from every possible shot that could make the MCU feel more cohesive?

Comment: I'm not that familiar with the NYC skyline, where should Avengers tower be in that picture?  I'd guess the tall black building on the left edge.

Comment: Not necessarily that specific image, but that scene, in particular, did a lot of sweeping shots of the entire skyline without one nod to the universe in which it belongs.

Comment: Maybe Luke’s just standing right in front of it.

Comment: +1 As I noticed the same thing and was my biggest annoyance in Dardevil. As for its location, it's built on top of the MetLife/PanAm building.

Comment: Is it the right part of the city, though? Is the Flatiron Building visible in any shots? The Empire State Building? It would have been a nice touch, but NYC is a big place, and not every building is visible from every spot.

Answer (score 35):

It was certainly in the show's [teaser trailer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sSCJj3nOSfQ) as well as the poster shots for the show, but **not** in the show itself.

[image]

There were, as you've noted, several skyline shots over the course of the series. Adding a fake building to each one, every single time would have added considerable expense to the show's budget

If I had to guess, the makers probably decided that the million-dollar pricetag of adding a CGI building to the skyline, **merely to satisfy the one-in-a-thousand uberfan who might actually notice** simply wasn't worth it.

Comment: Is that figure just a spitball or did you actually find a VFX studio that charges a million dollars for one CGI building in a backdrop that is still in business?

Comment: @TylerH - It was completely off the top of my head. That being said, [this answer on Quora](https://www.quora.com/Why-are-CGI-effects-so-expensive) suggests that a pricetag of $80K per second wouldn't be over the odds. Assuming you wanted people to actually see your tower in the background rather than simply blurring past it, that would mean that you'd want it on-screen for at least 4-5 seconds. Times that by every time you want to film a skyline shot for the remainder of the series and you're easily looking at adding $800K to the budget, purely for the purposes of making six fans happy

Comment: A good read, but note that he says costs can approach $80,000 per *shot*, not per second. A shot is akin to a take; one shot can be a few seconds or it can be [the entire length of a film](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_shot_%28film%29). Also, they'd definitely just take a couple shots and recycle them to save money, rather than have a VFX team re-do the same scene for multiple shots. But I don't want to digress into a discussion on VFX production costs here on an answer)

Comment: @TylerH - Even if they mean "one 10 second take = $80K" (which I don't think they do, but who the hell cares?), that still equates to at least 2-3 shots *per series*. A considerable amount of money to do something very mundane and largely unnoticed by 99.9998% of viewers. That money could be better spent on an extra TV spot or some magazine advertising.

Comment: You'd be surprised at where money gets spent in tv and film production. :-P Like I said, they reuse shots all the time, especially for TV shows like that; $80,000 for a 10-second scene they can use up to a couple dozen times a season would be pretty good value. And it's absurd to think that only 5 to 10 (00.0002% of the average viewership of 5 million) people would notice something like that. *Thousands* of people notice easter eggs and tips of the hats in just about any movie or tv show. A pretty huge part of the success of this site is thanks to a massive interest in such things, after all.

Comment: I don't think calling out "uberfans" is really constructive. I would not, by any means, consider myself an "uberfan." I'm just a guy who likes good movies/shows. It was apparent to me it was missing the first time they showed the entire skyline. I wasn't thinking of looking for it. I just thought, "It's not there." Additionally, it's not really an easter-egg like a Stormtrooper hitting his head. You can miss that and not ruin the continuity of the story. A missing 130+ story tower from the skyline of New York which houses one of the main driving forces of the story in the MCU is however.

Comment: @MichaelIrigoyen - I would refer to anyone who **pauses & rewinds the show to see if something is missing** as an uberfan :-)

Comment: Erm, I thought about it enough to get a screen grab off the internet and ask a question. Never paused, rewound, or went looking too particularly deep for it.

Comment: @MichaelIrigoyen - And that's what makes you part of the 0.00002%. Most people wouldn't have noticed and most people who did notice wouldn't have gone looking for an answer.

Comment: In a shot like the one in the question, it wouldn't be practical to reuse their one effects shot of the Stark tower. Now I haven't seen the show, so J don't know for certain, but stock shots like you are proposing are only practical for establishing shots, without characters or any particular scene going on inside them.

Comment: I didn't even realize Jessica Jones was part of the same universe as the Avengers until reading this question...

Comment: @Joe They reference the alien invasion and the Hulk multiple times.

Answer (score -4):

In the movie Avengers:Age of Ultron, it is shown that the Avengers HQ is shifted to another place, a greeny flatland, and not the tower. Let's assume that the events occurring in jessica jones is after Avengers2 events.

Comment: ...And therefore?

Comment: It doesn't matter that the Avengers HQ has moved; Stark Tower still exists.